# Display only one row for identical entries in mysql

Tags: mysql

Let's say you have a table with multiple identical entries and you want to show only the first one of each.

```
userid  |  event
1           01-01-2017
2           09-12-2016
2           05-06-2017
2           09-12-2016
3           10-03-2017   
...
```

and you want to display only one date (e.g. the minimal one per user):

```
userid  |  event
1           01-01-2017
2           09-12-2016
3           10-03-2017   
  ....
```

Normally I would try a subquery:

```
SELECT userid, event FROM table as A 
WHERE event=(SELECT min(event) FROM table as B WHERE A.userid = B.userid )
```

but in mySQL this displays 2 rows for userid=2, since that user has 2 identical minimal dates.

How can you limit the no. of rows to just one?

Comment: A simple `group by` is sufficient.

Comment: First: Store dates as dates. Next: Tables in an RDBMS require PRIMARY KEYS - otherwise they're not really tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT userid, event
FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM YourTable t WHERE t.userid = userid AND event > t.event
)
```

OR

```
SELECT a.id, a.rev, a.contents
  FROM (SELECT userid, Event,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Event ORDER BY userid DESC) rank
          FROM YourTable) a
 WHERE a.rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding `DISTINCT` to your `SELECT`?

Comment: thanks both, definitely DISTINCT works. I was trying LIMIT (as opposed to TOP in SQL Server) and still getting multiple entries.